# yahoo_fin get_balance_sheet() doesn't return any data

Tags: python, yfinance

I am using yahoo_fin to get some fundamental data and it is working fine for PE, PS ratio etc. but when using get_balance_sheet(), it return no data. Any suggestion? Thanks

```
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si
sheet = si.get_balance_sheet("AAPL")
```

Get PE ratio is fine

```
quote = si.get_quote_table("aapl")
quote["PE Ratio (TTM)"]
22.01
```

Comment: Maybe the library is broken. Go ask the maintainer.

Comment: Do you have a hard requirement to use yahoo_fin? Yahoo_fin has not been updated in over a year. Probably better to migrate to the Yfinance (https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance) library because it has more recent updates

Comment: Thanks Karatekraft. It is strange. I just used yfinance and aapl = yf.Ticker("AAPL"), then aapl.balance_sheet, it is also empty. If I use data = yf.download(tickers='AAPL') to download price, it is not empty and it does have data from 1980. I am thinking maybe it is related to yf.Ticker() module which is not working either? Thanks for your help